# Unable to run on iOS Simulator from Visual Studio on Windows

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, blazor

## The Issue

Developing on Windows with Visual Studio, and trying to run my app in iOS Simulator.

I'm not fussy whether the Simulator runs locally on my Windows machine, or on the Mac itself.

The Mac is "connected" from within Visual Studio, and Visual Studio successfully installed any missing libraries it required remotely on the Mac.

My app runs wonderfully on Android in both the Android simulator and physical devices.

But I'm unable to get the iOS Simulator to run when launched from Visual Studio.

## Environment

Windows machine:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2019 Preview 16.11.0 Preview 3
- Xamarin Mobile Blazor Bindings (doesn't to seem to be relevant, as I've tried creating other brand new iOS-related projects from within VS, with the same result).

Mac

- MacBook Air, running Big Sur.
- Xamarin.iOS14.20.0.24
- Xcode 12.5.1
- Simulator 12.5.1

## Different Scenarios Tried

### Scenario 1 - Enabled Remote Simulator to Windows

1. Visual Studio → Options → Xamarin → iOS Settings → Simulator - Checked "Remote Simulator to Windows".
2. Selected "iPhoneSimulator".
3. Selected iOS project from solution "BlazorHybridApp.iOS".
4. Selected from the list of available devices "iPod touch (7th generation) iOS 14.5)".
5. Clicked "Run".

[image]

#### Scenario 1 - Result within Visual Studio on Windows

[image]

### Scenario 2 - Disabled Remote Simulator to Windows

1. Visual Studio → Options → Xamarin → iOS Settings → Simulator - UNCHECKED "Remote Simulator to Windows".
2. Selected "iPhoneSimulator".
3. Selected iOS project from solution "BlazorHybridApp.iOS".
4. Selected from the list of available devices "iPod touch (7th generation) iOS 14.5)".
5. Clicked "Run".

#### Scenario 2 - Result within Visual Studio on Windows

Error message:

> error MT0069: The app directory '/Users/macbook/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/BlazorHybridApp.iOS/373192a984aab952b21bd389276fc38f881a1f70c8927669096f762b8fab1f51/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/BlazorHybridApp.iOS.app' does not exist.

I checked on the MacBook, and indeed the folder does not exist (I'd expect it to be auto-created as part of the build?).

So, I manually created the folder on the Mac, and reran from Visual Studio with the same settings selected.

#### Scenario 2 - 2nd Result within Visual Studio on Windows

Error message:

> error MT1008: Failed to launch the simulator: Could not find required file '/Users/macbook/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/BlazorHybridApp.iOS/373192a984aab952b21bd389276fc38f881a1f70c8927669096f762b8fab1f51/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/BlazorHybridApp.iOS.app/Info.plist'.

I checked on the MacBook, and the specified file does not exist. In fact the folder I manually created is empty.  I'm assuming this is where Xcode should be generating the binaries, etc.?

Despite the error message, on the MacBook, the Simulator DID launch, but did not launch my app.

## Other Info

### Big Sur/Xcode newly installed

This is a virgin MacBook, so no configuration changes have been made to the OS or Xcode.

### Confirmed Simulator is working on MacBook

I have checked that the Simulator is working ok on the MacBook, by creating a new App project on the MacBook from within Xcode and running it on the Simulator.

### Even tried Visual Studio 2022

Out of desperation, I have also tried downloading Visual Studio 2022 Preview which also has the required mobile dev support, but got the same issues.

## Any ideas?

Can anyone offer any advice? Would be very gratefully received.

Comment: It is annoying for ios testing on Windows sometimes (Like running ios project but no simulator). And Android ok only means your code is fine, not your ios project settings or ios environment, so post "ios build" in ios project properties might help. Also could try to 1. Delete "bin" and "obj" folders manually and rebuild. 2. Set custom entitlements to "Entitlements.plist" for simulator platform. 3. Try real device (remove entitlements setting). 4. Try stable version VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Scenario 1`, it is a known issue and [it has been reported here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2019-1694-cannot-connect-to-ios-simulator-xcode/1412563) .

[According to the latest reply](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2019-1694-cannot-connect-to-ios-simulator-xcode/1412563#T-N1471930) , there will be a release for this issue soon .

For `Scenario 2` , I would suggest you

1. Update everything to the latest `stable` version (vs for windows , vs for mac , Xcode).
2. Delete `bin` and `obj` folders in Forms and iOS project , rebuild and try again .
3. If problem persists try to create a new project and test .

Comment: Thank you so much for the info.

I managed to get it to work using the most recent "workaround" outlined in the thread you linked to, namely Visual Studio 2019 (16.9.4) with Xcode 12.4 running on the Mac.

I feel like I've wasted several days on this, but happy now that I can move forward again.

Thanks again. It really is appreciated :)